# No such file or directory in python docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python script that reads files, but when I try to port it to a docker container, it throws an error No such file or directory in python docker

python:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"//some/LogFiles$"):
        for filename in files:
            if "RSPowerBI" in filename:
                file = filename
    with open(fr'//some/LogFiles$/{file}') as fd:
        lines = fd.readlines()
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.7
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --default-timeout=100 future
WORKDIR /check
COPY . /check

RUN pip install  -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "/check/errors.py" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  bot2:
    image: first3
    build: ./
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - //some/LogFiles$:/check/some/LogFiles$
```

Comment: please provide file structure, the actual error and how you run your compose file.

remember that docker-compose has cache after first built of the local image.
I would recommend building the image manually and not part of the docker compose file. this will avoid "cache" mistakes.

Comment: If you expect `//some/LogFiles$` to resolve to the UNC path `\\some\LogFiles$` you need to install some sort of support for that in the Docker container. The common Linux component for this is Samba. Though perhaps a better solution is to mount the path as a volume in Docker like you already do; but then your script should use the path within the container where the volume is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your Python script to:

```
import os

log_files_path = '/check/some/LogFiles$'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(log_files_path):
    for filename in files:
        if "RSPowerBI" in filename:
            file_path = os.path.join(log_files_path, filename)
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                with open(file_path) as fd:
                    lines = fd.readlines()
                    # process the file contents
            else:
                print(f"File not found: {file_path}")
```

Comment: What have you changed?  Why does it help?